# How to seperate strings and add them back together?

Tags: xcode

I am currently building an app in xcode and I have something i'm stuck on... for example if the total of a question came to 15 how do you seperate the "1" and "5" and add those two number and recieve six? and i only want to display the six for my pp user to see

9+6 = 15 
nut instead i want it to display as 9+6= 15/6

Comment: Xcode supports multiple languages, so it is important to specify which language you are asking this question about.

Answer (score 1):

The wording of your post is a little confusing. Are you asking how to separate numbers into their individual digits, and then do things with those digits?

Not sure exactly what language you're writing in here, but in C:

```
int firstDigit = 0;
int secondDigit = 0;
int result = 0;
int num = 15;

firstDigit = num % 10; // 15 % 10 = 5
num /= 10; // 15 / 10 = 1
secondDigit = num % 10; // 1 % 10 = 1
result = firstDigit + secondDigit; // 5 + 1 = 6
```

Taking a number modulo 10 allows you to easily isolate the trailing digit.

You could even throw the above logic (isolate trailing digit, chop off trailing digit) into a loop to deal with arbitrarily-long numbers (within reason, of course).

Comment: +1 for a quick and efficient use of modulo (algorithms class 101) and for your good interpretation of this guy's question.

Comment: Thank you, Savagewood :)

Comment: thank you and i am actually making a alpanumeric calcultor and when you time in a name like "dog" it adds the value of each letter together. pretend it came up to 16. In the total box i need it to appear as "16/7"  - Savagewood